# Bootstrap Does Not Recognize Two Menu Navigations In Mobile Devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, frontend

I'm making a site in Bootstrap and I wanted to make two navigation menus.. So I coded this:

```
    <?php require_once 'php/functions/edu_functions.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Gooyanet</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
        <link href="css/head.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">
        <div id="wrapperDiv">
            <div id="stickyNavigation">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default BHoma">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right BHoma">
                                    <li><a href="#">ورود به حساب کاربری</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">ایجاد حساب کاربری</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">همکاری به عنوان مترجم زبان</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="searhBox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo.png" width="150" height="30">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                                </span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <div id="mainNavigation">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                        </form>
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                              </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                            </nav>
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So if you run this on an html document which connects to Bootstrap styles ,you will notice that everything works fine except when you minimize the screen to see how the menu navigations works  in mobile devices...

I mean when I hover over the button of menu navigation 1 it works correctly:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4h3e.png)

But when I hover over the button of menu navigation 2, again it shows me the top menu rather that main menu items:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyjsb.png)

I don't know why this thing happens ,I also tried replacing codes with default menu navigation but wasn't useful yet!

So if you have any idea on this ,please let me know... thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both navs have `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`

You need to change the id and data target on one of your menus.

Comment: I edited the second menu to this: class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2"

Comment: Did you change the data-target attribute for the button to match the new id?